# Python-mysql-replication get the cdc in variable

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, cdc

I'm using Python library Python-MySQL-replication and I don't know how to get the values in the variable since it's displayed in the console when I dump it binlogevent.dump() I want to get the CDC and upload it into Postgres.
I will be thankful to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have come across this issue and found a workaround. We can get the console output into a variable as shown in the below code sample.

```
from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
import sys
import io
import pandas as pd

old_stdout = sys.stdout
new_stdout = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = new_stdout

mysql_settings = {'host': 'localhost', 'port': 3306, 'user': 'root', 'passwd': 'password'}
log_stream = BinLogStreamReader(connection_settings = mysql_settings, server_id=100)

for binlogevent in log_stream:
    binlogevent.dump()

change = new_stdout.getvalue()
change_lst = change.split('--')
log_stream.close()
df = pd.DataFrame({'cdc' : change_lst})
```